# HTML / Javascript: Should I encode, escape, or sanitize user-generated strings for alt attributes (<img/> tags)?

Tags: javascript, html, security, user-generated-content

There seems to be many accepted answers regarding if one needs to encode user-generated HTML attributes (the `alt` attribute of an image for instance), 'escape' them, or 'sanitize' them.

I am wondering: If I am rendering user-generated alt attributes for img elements, how should I encode them (if at all), should I both encode and sanitize? Should I both sanitize and escape?

If I know any character has the possibility of showing up how should I process this user-generated string before setting it as an alt attribute?

Comment: "the alt attribute of an image for instance" — For instance? Beware. The answer will vary depending on the attribute.

Comment: Santiziation has little to do with security. How you ecape depends on the (unspecified) mechanism you are using to generate them from the input.

Comment: Regardless of mechanism, all I know is any character is possible to appear in these alt attributes.

Comment: While you might have any character provided as input, **how** you escape is **still** dependant on the mechanism you are using to generate the attribute from that input.

Comment: I am using React.js to generate the markup in which this user-generated string is being used as an alt attribute of an `img` tag.

Answer (score 0):

> I am using React.js to generate the markup in which this user-generated string is being used as an alt attribute of an img tag

Assuming you mean that you have something along the lines of:

```
<img alt={this.props.alt} />
```

… then no, you don't need to do anything. React works on the DOM. You aren't generating HTML source code, so special characters in the data can't be used to inject JavaScript through an XSS vulnerability.

Comment: So even if the prop in question `this.props.alt` contains markup, or a script tag, or special character, I still don't need to encode or process this string in any way?

Comment: @connected_user — That's what I said.

Comment: Well, technically setting the alt attribute via a prop is in fact generating HTML source code is it not?

Comment: Ah, okay I see.

Answer (score -1):

Sanitizing is required so there are no issues with displaying the string. If you are storing the alt attribute in a database then yyou should definitely escape the string.